# How do I draw more than just points in 3D?

Tags: 3d, javascript

I'm currently working on a 3D rendering engine in JavaScript. I've successfully rendered a cube and can rotate it. My cube is represented by 3D points in an array (`[x, y, z]`):

```
var cube = [[-20,-20,5],[20,-20,5],[-20,20,5],[20,20,5],
[-20,-20,-5],[20,-20,-5],[-20,20,-5],[20,20,-5]];
```

Now that I can render a basic cube I'd like to try rendering something more complicated to make sure my math works well. It's there a standard 3D object file i can import and use or I have to manually specify the 3D positions of every vertex like I did with the cube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely familiar with it, but I think that for *your* convenience, I would take a look into the [Wavefront .obj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) file format.

As I understand, a *lot* of 3d software implement this file format as a convenience to transfer from one 3d app to another.

Since the format is text based, you could 'code' your first shapes at first by hand, and then use a 3d software like [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) to make more complex objects.

You'll have to change the way you "read" your 3d objects, however, but it's for the best :)

Another advantage of using an open file format is that you'll already have a bunch of features right away, without having the burden of thinking how to structure them.

Be aware that different software use different hand-ness and coordinate system convention, so it may differ a bit from your implementation (for instance, a software might think the `y` axis is up, while another, or your own, thinks that `z` axis is up.

Comment: Thank you, i researched lot more about 3d modeling, 3d objects, wavefront, etc and wrote a .obj importer and a parser and modified my draw algorithm to be able to draw .obj models.
Right now my engine can render, rotate, escale and translate imported 3d .obj objects.

I had some troubles with faces, vertex and indices but i solve it so i can draw the triangles where they have to be.

Right now i'm working in ilumination and shadow based on facing orientation.

Thanks for your answer, it opened many new doors ;)

Comment: @RDeving glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at existing 3d model formats like Wavefront or Collada. They usually contain much more than a list of vertices, but you could write a function that extracts that particular details. Once you can extract vertices I'd look into rendering polygons.